# SAP Hybris- Spartacus Initialization error using ant initialize

Tags: ant, sap-commerce-cloud, spartacus-storefront

Getting the below error while performing the **ant initialize** command as part of setting up Spartacus storefront. The build is getting failed. PFB the details of the error.
Noted this issue on Hybris 2105.9 version.
ant initialize  was successful when the Hybris version was 2105.3

[image]

Comment: Did you try . ./setantenv.sh before this command?

Comment: Yes. I am trying this in a Windows machine and executed the below command setantenv.bat before initializing.

Comment: Did you install the nodejs?